# Symfony 3 - Login with extra field

Tags: php, symfony-3.3

I need to login users with 3 fields
- email
- password
- office (an entity with a oneToMany relation with my user entity)

I already have a provider based on my user entity

```
providers:
    admin:
        entity: { class: AdminBundle\Entity\User, property: email }
```

Logging with email / password work without any problem.

I need now to add an extra check as a same email can have multiple account (one per office) with different password, so in my login form, i have added an extra field Office (a choiceType referencing the offices IDs).

How can I pass this extra field information to my custom LoadUserByUsername to add a check on office so i have the couple email / office validated : WHERE u.office = :office AND u.email = :email.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you try like this

**security.yml**

```
security:
# ...

   providers:
       our_db_provider:
            entity:
                 class: AppBundle:User
```

and you need write mapping for that

```
// src/AppBundle/Repository/UserRepository.php
namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface
 {
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
      {

       return $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('u')
            ->from('YourBundle:User', 'a')
            ->join('YourBundle:Office', 'b', 'WITH', 'b.id = a.officeid')
            ->where('b.officeid = :office')
            ->ANDwhere('a.username = :username')
            ->setParameter('username', $username)
            ->setParameter('office', $office)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
       }
   }
```

source [symfony document](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html)

Comment: Thanks but i need to have both properties validated. I want : u.office = :office AND u.email = :email

Comment: where('u.office = :office OR u.email = :email') its working right

Comment: if the post helps you ,can mark vote and right answer

Comment: Office is not like username, it is another entity. I need to have both office entity valid coupled with an email. For exemple i can have test@test.com existing in office id 1 and office id 2 with differents passwords. So the check MUST be WHERE u.office = :office AND u.email = :email with office as an entity.

Comment: Thanks, i know how to join query but the question is : how to get the POSTED office VALUE and use it to validate authentification

Comment: Thanks, but how do you get from the $office as only $username is avariable as parameter ?

Comment: Give me some time let me check and let you know